# Is the sub-level set of a concave function convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose I have a set defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
S=\{ x: f(x) \le c\}
\end{align*}
where $f(x)$ is continuous  and  concave function defined over some $x \in K$ where $K$ is compact and convex. Note, that $S \subset K$. Is the set $S$ convex or non-convex?
I would really like it to be convex for my purpose but I am not sure.

**Here is what I tried.** Let $x_1,x_2 \in S$ then
\begin{align*}
f(\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2) \ge \alpha f(x_1)+(1-\alpha) f(x_2)
\end{align*}
but how to proceed next. The above doesn't tell me anything. 
Would be grateful, for any input you can have.

Comment: How can a non-negative function be strictly concave? Do you have an example of such a function?

Comment: Have you looked at examples?  There is no such thing, by the way, as a "concave set".

Comment: @MichaelGrant . I corrected it to concave.

Comment: I would still like to see a specific example. Without restricting the domain the only one I can think of is constant.

Comment: Actully, maybe this was the problem I didn't include that $x \in K$ which is compact and convex. I added it to the problem formulation.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Here  is an example. entropy $h(X+Z)$ where $Z$ is Gaussian normal random variable. Then $h(X+Z)$ is strictly convex over set of probability density distributions on $X$.

Comment: Getting there. The restricted domain enables this to be non-negative, but in an extended-valued sense it certainly is not. Still: in general, the superlevel set of a concave function is not a convex set. The question you need to ask is if entropy is *quasiconvex*. I do not believe it is, but it's possible.

Comment: Ok. Thank. I don't even know what that is?

Comment: [Here you go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function). Unfortunately, the definition of a quasiconvex function is a function for whom $S$ is a convex set :-) So what you are seeking to prove is precisely what the definition is.